# How to target a condition in pandas after grouping?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm learning how to use Pandas and I cannot find a solution to my problem. I would like to select only rows where '**cause**' == '**earthquakes**' by grouping '**occurred_on**'. I have my code below here:

```
total_Earthquakes_PerYear = df.\
        groupby(df['occurred_on'].dt.year)\
        ['cause'].value_counts()
total_Earthquake_PerYear
```

Output:

```
occurred_on  cause            
1969         earthquake           322
             nuclear explosion      1
1970         earthquake           344
             nuclear explosion      1
1971         earthquake           386
1972         earthquake           388
1973         earthquake           394
             nuclear explosion      6
             explosion              1
```

How do I go about getting rows where '**cause**' == '**earthquakes**'?

I tried going with this:

```
total_Earthquakes_PerYear = df[df['cause' == 'earthquake']].groupby(df['occurred_on'].dt.year)['cause'].count()
```

But still nothing. Thanks!

Comment: `df[df['cause'] == 'earthquake']`

Comment: Doesn't help ...

Answer (score 1):

The full line from my comment would be

```
total_Earthquakes_PerYear = (
     df[df['cause'] == 'earthquake']
    .groupby(df['occurred_on'].dt.year)
    ['cause'].value_counts()
)
```

Or you could have all the causes per year and filter only earthquakes

```
total_PerYear = df.\
    groupby(df['occurred_on'].dt.year)\
    ['cause'].value_counts()

total_Eathquakes_PerYear =  \
    total_PerYear[total_PerYear.cause == 'earthquake']
```